# Why is my TcpClient not sending information? (C#)

Tags: c#, tcp, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm making a simple tool that tells you when a client connects via Tcp. For some reason it doesn't send it the first time the program is ran, but it sends it only the second time

eg: Double click program - nothing
Double click it again, it runs the TcpClient stuff.

My Code to tell when someone connects:

```
public void ListenForClients()
    {
        while (listening == true)
        {
            TcpClient currClient = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            clients.Add(currClient);

            byte[] b = new byte[100];
            Socket s = listener.AcceptSocket();
            int k = s.Receive(b);
            string ClientInfo = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
            {
                ClientInfo = ClientInfo + Convert.ToChar(b[i]).ToString();
            }

            clientHandler(currClient, ClientInfo);
        }
    }

    public void clientHandler(TcpClient client, string ClientInfo)
    {
        clientID++;
        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                this.Text = "Network Monitor - Connections: " + clientID.ToString();
            }));

        listView1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {

                IPEndPoint IP = ((IPEndPoint)client.Client.RemoteEndPoint);
                ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(new string[] { clientID.ToString(), IP.ToString(), ClientInfo });
                this.listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
            }));
    }
```

My code for the client sending the Tcp Information

```
  TcpClient me = new TcpClient();
            me.Connect("127.0.0.1", 2222);
            Stream sendData = me.GetStream();
            ASCIIEncoding text = new ASCIIEncoding();
            byte[] clientInfoByte = text.GetBytes("lol");
            sendData.Write(clientInfoByte,0,clientInfoByte.Length);
            sendData.Close();
            me.Close();
```

Comment: `AcceptTcpClient` and `AcceptSocket` for the same client, does not seem right at all !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replacing

```
Socket s = listener.AcceptSocket();
```

with

```
Socket s = currClient.Client;
```

**Note :**

```
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
{
    ClientInfo = ClientInfo + Convert.ToChar(b[i]).ToString();
}
```

can be written as

```
ClientInfo = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);
```